# Is it possible to use ~/.ssh/config to handle '-t create' switches?

Tags: ssh, sourceforge

As you may know, SourceForge offers a shell service. According to their [Shell Access info page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Shell%20service) the command to get a shell is this:

```
ssh -t USER,PROJECT@shell.sourceforge.net create
```

This queues up a shell on their end and eventually drops you into one. I'd like to somehow add this to my `~/.ssh/config`. I'm at a loss for what the `-t` switch is called in `config` and also how to pass the `create` argument.

Does anyone know how such an entry might look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the research I have done before (and refreshed just now), I don't believe that that option exists [there are many cases of complaints on the topic, however].  ([The man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) seems to confirm this).

That being said, rather than just tell you "no", one possible work around would be to make an `alias` in your `profile` (in many cases, located in `~/.bash_profile`, but is different on some systems).

```
alias sshSF="ssh -t USER,PROJECT@shell.sourceforge.net"
```

Then since it is an alias, you could call `sshSF create` and "create" would be an argument. If you have a key, you can of course specify that with `-i` as well.

Comment: I was afraid of that.